# ZingChart nodes are not selected

Tags: javascript, charts, zingchart

I'm using ZingChart  and I'm trying to add 3 different series to a line chart.
The problem is that when I do this, the select marker does not work.
What seems to happen is that the second and third series don't receive any events as I would expect and instead other nodes receive them.
Is what I'm trying to do invalid?

I want to group these dates in 3 sets so that I set a different marker to each one. If I could set the marker in some other way that would be acceptable too.

```
var myConfig = {
  graphset:[    
    {
      type:"line",
      x:"0%", 
      y:"0%",
      height:"100%",
      width:"100%",

      plot: {
        selectionMode : 'multiple',

        selectedMarker:{ //sets the styling for selected marker (per series)
          type:"star5",
          backgroundColor:"white",
          borderColor:"black",
          borderWidth:2,
          size:8
        }
      },

      scaleY: {
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 10,
        step: 1
      },

      scaleX: {
    //    minValue: 1480883248000,
    //    step: 720000,//12min
        transform: {
          type: 'date',
          all: '%m/%d/%y  %h:%i %A'
        },
      },

      series: [
        {
          text: 'f',
          values: [

            [1480883248000, 1],
            [1480898368000, 1],
            [1480883248000, 1],
            [1480883968000, 1],
            [1480884688000, 1],
            [1480885408000, 1],
            [1480886128000, 1],
            [1480886848000, 1],
            [1480887568000, 1],
            [1480888288000, 1],
            [1480889008000, 1],
            [1480889728000, 1],
            [1480890448000, 1],
            [1480891168000, 1],
            [1480891888000, 1],
            [1480892608000, 1],
            [1480893328000, 1],
            [1480894048000, 1],
            [1480894768000, 1],
            [1480895488000, 1],
            [1480896208000, 1],
            [1480896928000, 1],
           /* [1480897648000, 1, 'n'],
            [1480898368000, 1, 'n'],
            [1480899088000, 1, 'n'],
            [1480899808000, 1, 'n'],
            [1480900528000, 1, 'n'],*/


          ],

          marker: {
            type: 'circle',
            size: 2
          }

        },

        {
           text: 'a',
          values: [[1480883728000, 1]],


          marker: {
            type: 'triangle',
            size: 7
          }


        },
        {
              text: 'n',
          values: [[1480894168000, 1]],

          marker: {
            type: 'square',  //circle
            size: 7
          }
        }

      ]     
    }
  ]
};

zingchart.render({ 
    id : 'myChart', 
    data : myConfig, 
    height: 400, 
    width: "100%" 
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple things you need to do.

1) Apply the `selectedMarker` attribute to each individual series object. Series takes the same values as plot. Thus, you can overwrite and redefine individual styling within each `series` object.

```
{
      text: 'n',
      values: [[1480894168000, 1]],

      marker: {
        type: 'square',  //circle
        size: 7
      },
      selectedMarker:{ //sets the styling for selected marker (per series)
        type:"star6",
        backgroundColor:"black",
        borderColor:"black",
        borderWidth:2,
        size:8
      }
    }
  ]     
}
```

If you are using the data posted, you must adjust two things.

1) Adjust the `z-index` of the first plot (series[0]). Making this `z-index` a lower value will allow you to click on plots placed on top of it.

2) Two of your timestamps in `series[0].values[1]` and `series[0].values[2]` are plotted beyond the furthest point in the `values` array and plotted before the first point in the `values` array. If you keep the data the same and click on the blue line, it always looks like its selecting the first point. This is true because it's really selecting the 3rd point which the line spans the first half of the plot.

Try clicking on the blue line for the first half of the chart
[issue chart here](https://demos.zingchart.com/view/GNQHG4A8)

If you still don't believe me, fork the demo above and change the first couple values from 1 to 2 and 3 etc...

The final product (fixed data) looks like the following.

```js
var myConfig = {
  graphset:[    
    {
      type:"line",

      plot: {
        selectionMode : 'multiple',
      },

      scaleY: {
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 10,
        step: 1
      },

      scaleX: {
    //    minValue: 1480883248000,
    //    step: 720000,//12min
        transform: {
          type: 'date',
          all: '%m/%d/%y  %h:%i %A'
        },
      },

      series: [
        {
          zIndex:300,
          text: 'f',
          values: [

            [1480883248000, 1],
            //[1480898368000, 1],
            //[1480883248000, 1],
            [1480883968000, 1],
            [1480884688000, 1],
            [1480885408000, 1],
            [1480886128000, 1],
            [1480886848000, 1],
            [1480887568000, 1],
            [1480888288000, 1],
            [1480889008000, 1],
            [1480889728000, 1],
            [1480890448000, 1],
            [1480891168000, 1],
            [1480891888000, 1],
            [1480892608000, 1],
            [1480893328000, 1],
            [1480894048000, 1],
            [1480894768000, 1],
            [1480895488000, 1],
            [1480896208000, 1],
            [1480896928000, 1],

          ],

          marker: {
            type: 'circle',
            size: 2
          },
          selectedMarker:{ //sets the styling for selected marker (per series)
            type:"star5",
            backgroundColor:"black",
            borderColor:"black",
            borderWidth:2,
            size:8
          }

        },

        {
          text: 'a',
          values: [[1480883728000, 1]],


          marker: {
            type: 'triangle',
            size: 7
          },
          selectedMarker:{ //sets the styling for selected marker (per series)
            type:"star3",
            backgroundColor:"black",
            borderColor:"black",
            borderWidth:2,
            size:8
          }


        },
        {
          text: 'n',
          values: [[1480894168000, 1]],

          marker: {
            type: 'square',  //circle
            size: 7
          },
          selectedMarker:{ //sets the styling for selected marker (per series)
            type:"star6",
            backgroundColor:"black",
            borderColor:"black",
            borderWidth:2,
            size:8
          }
        }

      ]     
    }
  ]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id: 'myChart', 
 data: myConfig, 
 height: '100%', 
 width: '100%' 
});
```

```css
html, body {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#myChart {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 min-height:150px;
}
.zc-ref {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="myChart"><a class="zc-ref" href="https://www.zingchart.com">Powered by ZingChart</a></div>
 </body>
</html>
```